# What is the font used on the current logo?

Tags: support, logo

I like the font, but I'm having trouble finding it on widely-known sites like dafont. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [mentioned in a post over on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59502/are-the-beta-stack-exchange-site-logos-generated-automatically/59514#59514) that I think the font is [Sketch Block](http://www.dafont.com/sketch-block.font?nb_ppp=50).